# How to navigate the navigationcontroller rootviewcontrollr subview controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

in my application i mentioned the tab bar controller with 2 tabs tab1 and tab2.And each tab having the navigation view controller with root view controllers.And my scenario is like below

tab1 -> viewcontroller1 *(navigationcontroller rootviewcontroller)* -> viewcontroller2.

So now i want to move directly from app delegate to view controller2.How is it possible.

I did this one like this in app delegate. But it's moving to viewcontroller1.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
self.tabbarController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarcontroller"];
[self.tabbarController setSelectedIndex:1];
 viewcontroller2 *view =(viewcontroller2 *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];

[self.tabbarController.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController=self.tabbarController;
```

Comment: Can you push viewcontroller2 as navigationController's top view?

Comment: in appDelegate --> did finish lounching with option write : Splash *vc2 = [[Splash alloc] initWithNibName:@"Splash" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];

Comment: setSelectedIndex:2 i think it will move to second viewcontroller

Comment: Your tab bar controller doe not have a navigation controller, so self.tabbarController.navigationController is nil.

Comment: self.tabbarcontroller.navigationcontroller is readonly.

Comment: I set the viewcontroller1 as tabitem with navigaitoncontroller only.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tab1 -> Viewcontroller1(navigationcontroller rootviewcontroller) -> Viewcontroller2
```

I have used this approach some times

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
self.tabbarController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarcontroller"];
[self.tabbarController setSelectedIndex:1];
viewcontroller1 *view1 =(viewcontroller1 *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewContro1llerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
viewcontroller2 *view2 =(viewcontroller2 *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];

[self.tabbarController.navigationController pushViewController:view1 animated:NO];
[self.tabbarController.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];

self.window.rootViewController=self.tabbarController;
```

Comment: Me also did the same thing with viewcontroller2.Is it worked for u?.I need to move to viewcontroller 2 directly from appdelegate.

Comment: Yes, but there is a little bit difference between mine and your code, I have pushed viewController1 first then 2 one.

Comment: I tried like u also,but it's showing viewcontroller1.Directly i want to show the viewcontroller 2.

Comment: check the self.tabbarController.navigationController.viewControllers value after adding the controller..

Comment: I did that one in storyboard.Once we select the tab,then viewcontroller1 will appear.If i clcikc any button on viewontroller1 then viewcontroller2 will appar.But now i want to show the viewcontroller2 when we select the tab.